# Dead Space 2 Communicator Filter FX

Tags: game-audio, sound-design

Dead Space 2 has awesome sound design.

One of the sounds I consider to be really well done is the communicator that Issac has holographic-ally at his disposal.

Example: http://youtu.be/AhrQNSVRttE?hd=1&t=5m16s
(Link should start at 5:16)

There are a number of good plug-ins that do this effect quite nicely with a preset, but what exactly is the plug-in doing to create this effect at its core. (not programmatic, but in sound design)

Its seems to be a bit of narrow-band EQ, slight distortion, and quite a bit of compression and/or limiting. Then on top of that SUM, you have the more digital bloops and filtered static that layer the transmission characteristic to the recording.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more or less got it. Highpass filter, compression, some distortion and a separate recording of bits and bursts of compressed white noise mixed in. Nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and you've probably already done it, but for the other RIG sounds (not the holographic), like the "warning" sound and stuff like that, there are definitely some granular fx on there. Try out Buffeater by twisted tools, it has some great stretch and smear stuff.